# How to check if any application is running in docker container?

Tags: docker, devops

How to check if any application is running in docker container ? What is the command for it.

Comment: Please expand your question. What language are you using? Are you refering to the command line? What OS are you on?

Answer (score 4):

You need to show auxiliary list of process. Try this.

```
docker exec -it <name-of-your-container> /bin/bash
# ps aux | grep "application-name-here"
```

Comment: This solution is not very elegant, you have to filter out the grep from ps output. Better use 'pgrep' like I does in my response or you can use a trick to make your string a regex: `ps aux | grep "[a]pp-name"`

Answer (score 2):

A container only runs one process.  If that process exits, the container exits too.  There's not anything to check beyond what you can see with `docker ps -a`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
// Access your container
docker exec -it <name of your container> bash

// List running processes in your container
ps
```

Comment: Through this we can enter into the application but unable to identify whether it is running or not.

Comment: @AffanNaim Try "top" instead of "ps" then?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `docker top <name of your container>` to check process running in your container.

Answer (score 1):

In only on line:

```
docker exec -it <name-of-your-container> pgrep -fl <application-name-here>
```

`pgrep` - look up or signal processes based on name and other attributes